# The following resources are missing a cache expiration How to set cache expiration for javascript file?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, iis, cache-expiration

net application. I'm using external javascript files in my application. When I test my site with page speed tool from google it says that following resources are missing a cache expiration. also some of the images and css files.

Can you give me please some examples how to set it and where exactly I need to set it.

Answer (score 2):

you can find what you are looking for right here:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=true

Setting the expiration data on files will "order" the browser to save those in cache for X amount of days.
you can set this header on File/Folder

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Is the only way to do it? can I specify expiration for each file separately? for example for some of the files I need to set expiration after 7 days and for other files after 1 month

Comment: yes you can, you can do it on a folder and/or on a file, with no problem at all.